# Reporting birt , script for data set the error is " Multiple exceptions occurred ."

Tags: javascript, java, report, birt

I have a problem when a run (view report ) , my script in before open :

```
Packages.java.lang.System.out.println("---------------------------" );


Packages.java.lang.System.out.println( "p_date : " + params["p_date"] );
Packages.java.lang.System.out.println( "p_dpt  : " + params["p_dpt"] );
Packages.java.lang.System.out.println( "p_contrat_type  : " + params["p_contrat_type"] );
Packages.java.lang.System.out.println( "parm1  : " + params["parm1"] );

this.queryText ="SELECT zy00.matcle ,zy00.nomuse ,zy00.prenom ,zy00.nompat ,agt_carriere( zy00.matcle, 'datfin', to_date('" +   params["p_date"]+ "','YYYY-MM-DD' )) dateF FROM zy00  WHERE typdos = 'SAL' " ;


if (params["p_contrat_type"].value ) {
   this.queryText = this.queryText + "  AND EXISTS ( SELECT 'x' FROM zyco WHERE ( zyco.nudoss, zyco.datcon) = (  SELECT c.nudoss, MAX( c.datcon ) FROM zyco c WHERE zyco.nudoss = c.nudoss AND c.datcon <= TO_date('"+ params["p_date"] +"','YYYY-MM-DD') AND zy00.nudoss = zyco.nudoss AND typcon = '"+ params["p_contrat_type"].value  + "'  GROUP BY c.nudoss  ))"
}



else if ( params["p_contrat_type"].value='')
{ this.queryText = this.queryText + "AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM zyco  WHERE ( zyco.nudoss, zyco.datcon ) = (  SELECT c.nudoss, MAX( c.datcon ) FROM zyco c   WHERE zyco.nudoss = c.nudoss AND c.datcon <= to_date('" + params["p_date"] +"','YYYY-MM-DD' ) GROUP BY c.nudoss) AND typcon = '" + params["p_contrat_type"]+"'  AND zy00.nudoss = zyco.nudoss )"
}

else if ( params["parm1"].value='false')
{this.queryText = this.queryText +" AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM zyes WHERE zy00.nudoss = zyes.nudoss AND zyes.datsor >= :p_date) "} 


else if (params["parm1"].value='true')
{this.queryText= this.queryText + " ( and exists (SELECT * FROM zyaf WHERE zy00.nudoss = zyaf.nudoss   AND zyaf.tyassi = '1' AND ( zyaf.nudoss, zyaf.dataff ) = (  SELECT c.nudoss, MAX( dataff ) FROM zyaf c WHERE zyaf.nudoss = c.nudoss  AND c.dataff <= '" + params["p_date"] +"' AND tyassi = '1'  GROUP BY c.nudoss)  AND servic = '" + params["p_dpt"] +"' AND sectio = :'" + params["p_unite"] +"')"}          

Packages.java.lang.System.out.println( this.queryText );
```

Comment: Can you post the error logs as well?

Comment: Your approach is quite insecure (SQL injection)...